# Google Sheet Query Group and Max issue

Tags: google-sheets-formula

[image]

```
A            B          C        D        E          F             G          H
Awardant    Event   Category    Vote    SumVotes    SumEvent    SumCategory SumAwardant 
Nominee 4   Main Event  category1   4    16       Last Event    category1   Nominee 1
Nominee 3   Main Event  category1   3    12       Last Event    category1   Nominee 3
Nominee 1   Main Event  category1   5    8        Last Event    category1   Nominee 4
Nominee 8   Main Event  category2   4    12       Last Event    category2   Nominee 5
Nominee 5   Main Event  category2   6    7        Last Event    category2   Nominee 8
Nominee 4   Main Event  category1   4    6        Last Event    category2   Nominee 2
Nominee 3   Main Event  category1   3    10       Main Event    category1   Nominee 1
Nominee 1   Main Event  category1   5    8        Main Event    category1   Nominee 4
Nominee 2   Main Event  category2   12   6        Main Event    category1   Nominee 3
Nominee 5   Main Event  category2   5    12       Main Event    category2   Nominee 2
Nominee 4   Last Event  category1   4    11       Main Event    category2   Nominee 5
Nominee 3   Last Event  category1   5    4        Main Event    category2   Nominee 8
Nominee 1   Last Event  category1   9               
Nominee 8   Last Event  category2   7               
Nominee 5   Last Event  category2   5               
Nominee 4   Last Event  category1   4               
Nominee 3   Last Event  category1   7               
Nominee 1   Last Event  category1   7               
Nominee 2   Last Event  category2   6               
Nominee 5   Last Event  category2   7
```

First I calculate the total Votes for each awardant for each event, category
The formula in cell E1 to Total Votes for each Awardant, Event, Category is:

```
query(A1:D1011,"select SUM(D), B,C,A group by B,C,A order by B,C, sum(D) desc label A 'SumAwardant ', B 'SumEvent', SUM(D) 'SumVotes', C 'SumCategory' ",-1)
```

Then I calculate the maxime votes for each event, category
The Formula in cell I1 to Obtain Maximum for each Event, Category is:

```
query(A1:D1011,"select SUM(D), B,C,A group by B,C,A order by B,C, sum(D) desc label A 'SumAwardant ', B 'SumEvent', SUM(D) 'SumVotes', C 'SumCategory' ",-1)
```

The formulas seem to work, however I need to determine which Awardant(s) the Maximun Total votes relate to within each Event, Category. Please can anyone advise me how I can change the formula to achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can determine what you want by using pivot table
[image]